# How to access sub domain folder from main domain in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I've a site- **mysite.com** and a sub domain **admin.mysite.com** . I want to access the the subdomain folder from the main site. The sub domain folder is **admin** and is in the same directory level as the main domain.

**Directory organisation is as:**

```
root/admin - sub domain folder
root/httpd - main domain folder
```

**What I want to access:**

```
root/admin/images/
```

**From:**

```
root/httpd/index.php
```

The PHP script must scan the above directory for images and then `echo` their **dir/http** path in the `<img>` tag in the main domain document.

Why do I need to access that - because images are uploded by the user in the sub domain. :|

Comment: Why not just connect to admin.example.com from the main domain? If that isn't what you want, .. will move one directory level, so if you wanted to access the admin folder, use ../admin etc. From the example you gave, an image will be located at ../admin/images/imagename.png

Comment: httpd is not just a folder. It's a domain folder. you connot dp '../admin' to get to the admin folder. The browser will always interpret it as mysite.com/admin/images.

Comment: Secondly, the no of images in the images folder will change, so i need to dynamically load them using php script than referencing every image as admin.mysite.com/image/i.jpg ... and so on. I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution to this.

Using `opendir()` function I was able to scan for the images in the sub domain directory.

```
$handle = opendir('../admin/images/');

   while($file = readdir($handle)){

        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){

            echo "<img src='http://admin.mysite.com/images"."/"."$file' />";

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define("IMG_DIRECTORY", "you subdomain upload folder");

$filename = $_GET['f'];
$filepath = IMG_DIRECTORY . $filename;

//if file does not exists
if( strlen($filename) == 0 || !is_file($filepath) ){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

$path_parts = pathinfo( $filename );
$file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];

header("Content-type:image/" . strtolower($file_ext));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$filename);

//For IE Save as filename bug
if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")){
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
}

@readfile(str_replace("@","",$filepath));
```

You can build a api page to do that

http://example.com/imageapi.php?f=sample.png

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the problem is that I need to scan the directory to get the Image file names too. So i guess the core problem is how to access/scan this folder using PHP :/.